# Which status code to use when an operation has already been done?

Tags: https, server, http-status-codes, status, http-put

Users will be able to share images in my project. But let's say that `user1` has already shared the image to `user2`, but `user1` tries to share the picture again to `user2`. What would be the appropriate status code for "already shared"?

Answer (score 0):

409 is the right status code. It means the item already exists.

In your case `"image already shared"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there a standard convention for this scenario. Status code 409 would highlight the fact the request was 1. Received and understood and 2. There was a server side conflict with processing and storing the data. Some other options would be 400, 403, and 422, but those could mean a variety of other issues with the request that could be misinterpreted.